# Why I can't update my one-to-one model's FileField in Django?

Tags: django, one-to-one, filefield

In order to add more features to the default model, I employed one-to-one filed in Django. Then I want to customize my update/edit Userprofile page. 
I rewrite the **update form** like this ：

```
{% load static %}
...

<div  id="block-center" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
          ...
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>
                <label for="id_location">Location:</label> <input class="form-control" placeholder="Location"type="text" name="location" value="{{user.profile.location}}"maxlength="30" id="id_location" />
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                {% if user.profile.upload.url%}
                <p class="file-upload">Currently: <img src="{{user.profile.upload.url}}" alt="Avatar" class="avatar"><br></p>
                <label for="id_upload">Change:</label> <input type="file" name="upload"  value="{{user.profile.upload}}" id="id_upload" />

                {% else%}
                <label for="id_upload">Avator:</label> <input type="file" name="upload"  value="{{user.profile.upload}}" id="id_upload" />
                {% endif %}
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
</div>
```

My **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    upload = models.FileField()
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

My **views.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.forms import UserForm,ProfileForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db import transaction
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        profile = request.user.profile
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('blog:index')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))

    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        profile = request.user.profile
    return render(request, 'profiles/profile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form,
        'profile':profile
    })
```

All other fields work well except the filefield upload in Userprofile model. I don't know why. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding enctype to your form tag:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

It's necessary when uploading files.